# Overlay one image with another in css

Tags: css

I have 4 images in a row. I want the third image to be overlayed on top of the second image but have not been able to successfully get it to work. Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/Asu7V/4/

```
<div style="width:1000px">
  <div class="x">
      <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_dae559818d30_128.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="x">
      <img src="http://scottsdalepethotel.com/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/cat-648150_128x128.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="x">
      <img src="http://playgo.ro/wp-content/themes/play3.0/play.png" />
  </div>    
  <div class="x">
      <img src="http://blog.sureflap.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Maru.jpg" />
  </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the play image in second div and use `position absolute` and `relative` to make it one above the another.

```
.x{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    height:128px;
  position:relative
}
.overlay_img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OgEGOpom/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be over 2nd image then wrap those 2 images in 1 div and give it `position:relative` then give your Image2 and image 3 `position:absolute` and `z-index:0 & z-index:1` respectively. And position them to `top:0; & left:0;` that should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use modern CSS and only need the third image to overlay the second (as in, you don't need to repeat this pattern in a lot of places), you can use the nth-child selector:

```
.x:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: -136px;
}
```

This will select the third item with the `x` class and move it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `margin` or `position`  property,you can achieve the overlayed view,

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Z7Y88/